# Remove rows from a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, select

I am trying to delete all `rows` from a `pandas df`. Specifically, when the `row` beneath `X` in `Col A` is empty. So if the `row` underneath `X` in `Col A` is empty I want to delete all those rows until there is a `string` underneath value `X`

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'A' : ['X','','','X','Foo','','X','Fou','','X','Bar'],           
    'B' : ['Val',1,3,'Val',1,3,'Val',1,3,'Val',1],
    'C' : ['Val',2,4,'Val',2,4,'Val',2,4,'Val',2],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Output:

```
      A    B    C
0     X  Val  Val
1          1    2
2          3    4
3     X  Val  Val
4   Foo    1    2
5          3    4
6     X  Val  Val
7   Fou    1    2
8          3    4
9     X  Val  Val
10  Bar    1    2
```

I have tried:

```
df = df[~(df['A'] == 'X').shift().fillna(False)]
```

But this deletes everything followed by X. I only want it to be deleted if the next row below X is empty.

Intended:

```
     A    B    C
0    X  Val  Val
1  Foo    1    2
2         3    4
3    X  Val  Val
4  Fou    1    2
5         4    4
6    X  Val  Val
7  Bar    1    2
```

Comment: where does `Foo` comes in row `1` and column `A`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand?

Comment: In intended part there is Foo in  row 1 and column A, I don't understand  by which logic it is there.

Comment: So If the isn't a value beneath Value `X` in `Col A` I want to delete all those rows until there is a value underneath Value `X`

Comment: @PeterJames123 does the df has always the same structure? like  the `X` every 3 rows?

Comment: It doesn't sorry. It's always at the start of the data frame. But it could be anywhere between 5-20 columns.

Comment: I realised `duplicated` mask is not necessary, so solution was simlify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
m1 = df['A'] == 'X'
g =  m1.cumsum()
m = (df['A'] == '') | m1

df = df[~m.groupby(g).transform('all')]
print (df)
      A    B    C
3     X  Val  Val
4   Foo    1    2
5          3    4
6     X  Val  Val
7   Fou    1    2
8          3    4
9     X  Val  Val
10  Bar    1    2
```

**Details**:

```
m1 = df['A'] == 'X'
g =  m1.cumsum()
m = (df['A'] == '') | m1

print (pd.concat([df,
                  df['A'] == 'X',
                  m1.cumsum(),
                  (df['A'] == ''), 
                  m,
                  m.groupby(g).transform('all'),
                  ~m.groupby(g).transform('all')], axis=1,
       keys=['orig','==X','g','==space','m', 'all', 'inverted all']))

   orig              ==X  g ==space      m    all inverted all
      A    B    C      A  A       A      A      A            A
0     X  Val  Val   True  1   False   True   True        False
1          1    2  False  1    True   True   True        False
2          3    4  False  1    True   True   True        False
3     X  Val  Val   True  2   False   True  False         True
4   Foo    1    2  False  2   False  False  False         True
5          3    4  False  2    True   True  False         True
6     X  Val  Val   True  3   False   True  False         True
7   Fou    1    2  False  3   False  False  False         True
8          3    4  False  3    True   True  False         True
9     X  Val  Val   True  4   False   True  False         True
10  Bar    1    2  False  4   False  False  False         True
```

**Explanation**:

1. Compare by `X` and create cumulative sum for groups starts with `X` to `g`
2. Chain 2 boolean masks - compared `X` and empty space to `m`
3. [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`DataFrameGroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html) for return `True`s for groups with only `True`
4. Last invert and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution:

```
(df['A'] == 'X').shift()
0       NaN
1      True
2     False
3     False
4      True
5     False
6     False
7      True
8     False
9     False
10     True
Name: A, dtype: object
In [15]:

(df['A'] == '')
Out[15]:
0     False
1      True
2      True
3     False
4     False
5      True
6     False
7     False
8      True
9     False
10    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
In [14]:

((df['A'] == '') & (df['A'] == 'X').shift())
Out[14]:
0     False
1      True
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

And the result is:

```
df[~((df['A'] == '') & (df['A'] == 'X').shift())]
Out[16]:
A   B   C
0   X   Val Val
2       3   4
3   X   Val Val
4   Foo 1   2
5       3   4
6   X   Val Val
7   Fou 1   2
8       3   4
9   X   Val Val
10  Bar 1   2
```

EDIT:
If you need you can do it in while loop.
    old_size_df = df.size
    new_size_df = 0

```
while old_size_df != new_size_df:
    old_size_df = df.size
    df = df[~((df['A'] == '') & (df['A'] == 'X').shift())]
    new_size_df = df.size

    A   B   C
0   X   Val Val
3   X   Val Val
4   Foo 1   2
5       3   4
6   X   Val Val
7   Fou 1   2
8       3   4
9   X   Val Val
10  Bar 1   2
```

Comment: Thanks @ Cezary.Sz. But I need to delete every row unless a string follows X. So the output should be from index 3 down. Index 0,2 should be removed and the row beneath X is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution with custom apply function:

```
d = ({
    'A' : ['X','','','X','Foo','','X','Fou','','X','Bar'],           
    'B' : ['Val',1,3,'Val',1,3,'Val',1,3,'Val',1],
    'C' : ['Val',2,4,'Val',2,4,'Val',2,4,'Val',2],
})
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

is_x = False
def fill_empty_a(row):
    global is_x
    if row['A'] == '' and is_x:
            row['A'] = None
    else:
            is_x = row['A'] == 'X'
    return row

(df.apply(fill_empty_a, axis=1)
   .dropna()
   .reset_index(drop=True))
#      A    B    C
# 0    X  Val  Val
# 1    X  Val  Val
# 2  Foo    1    2
# 3         3    4
# 4    X  Val  Val
# 5  Fou    1    2
# 6         3    4
# 7    X  Val  Val
# 8  Bar    1    2
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove the first row as well? It should include everything unless a string follows X